# Proxy Dom element gives invocation error

Tags: javascript, dom, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy of a dom element, in this example I used the the window object. When I run the code, I get an:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

however if I modify: `return Reflect.apply(method, this, arguments);`
with: `return Reflect.apply(method, target, arguments);`
everything works. If I create a proxy out of a self defined object like alice both versions works fine.

Is there a way to use `return Reflect.apply(method, this, arguments);` when creating a proxy of a dom object? Why is it not working?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <body>
hello
<script>

var alice = {
    firstname:'Alice',
    lastname:'Smith',
    secret:'secret',
    amount: 0,
    removeAmount : function(amount){
        this.amount = this.amount - amount;
    },

};


var handler = {

    get: function(target, name, receiver){
        console.log("get: "+ name);
        var method = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
        if (typeof method === "function"){
            return function () {
                return Reflect.apply(method, this, arguments);
            } 
        }
        return method;
    },
    set: function(target, name, value, receiver){
        console.log("set: "+ name);
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
    }

};


var p =  new Proxy(window,handler);
p.alert("http://www.w3schools.com");


</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to be called `window.alert`(window context) through a `Proxy` instance (another context), So you should set `window` as context explicitly as a second parameter `Reflect.Apply(method, window, arguments)`. Because at this point of code execution, `this` doesn't have reference to `window` anymore.

Comment: I don't understand why this does not have a reference to window anymore? As when you run the same example with a self made object it clearly keeps the reference. Is the issue maybe the browser does not like the fact i'm switching context, as the call to the proxy has a window context and once it leaves the proxy the context is changed?